# How to set Java environment path in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, java

I just installed JDK in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk` command,
after the installation where's the Java `bin` directory located? And how can I set the environment path for that directory? I have little experience with Ubuntu, can anyone give some advice or suggest any good website for reference?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

set  environment variables as follows

Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add following lines in end

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Then Log out and Log in ubuntu for setting up the paths...

Comment: why export JRE_HOME?

Comment: It didn't work for me and the previous version remained as default. I changed the order of the path to
`export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}`

and the version got updated. I think left to right priority works here.

Comment: Already solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: .bash_profile and .bashrc are specific to bash, whereas .profile is read by many shells in the absence of their own shell-specific config files. /etc/bash_profile (fallback /etc/profile) is read before the user's .profile for system-wide configuration.

Comment: Also you would have to logout and login for the changes to take effect for  /etc/profile but only close and open a new terminal if you change ~/.bashrc

Comment: Just add this...

export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/.local/jbr
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Answer (score 104):

Java is typically installed in `/usr/java`
locate the version  you have and then do the following:

Assuming you are using bash (if you are just starting off, i recommend bash over other shells) you can simply type in bash to start it.

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add the paths as follows:

for eg. vi `~/.bashrc`

insert following lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<your version of java>
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

after you save the changes, exit and restart your bash or just type in bash to start a new shell

Type in `export` to ensure paths are right.

Type in `java -version` to ensure Java is accessible.

Comment: perfect! thank you. NB: You might want to remove the default openJDK from your system as it appears first in the global path. So after the above script is loaded, you will only pic-up "javac" not java, because of the default openjk-jre.

~sudo apt-get remove openjdk-*~

Comment: I have probelm with it, I tried every method to update java, but still time my version is jdk1.7 but I set up the path to jdk1.8

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` restart bash without logout.

Answer (score 36):

Ubuntu installs openjdk6 to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk` path. So you will have the bin in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin`. Usually the classpath is automatically set for the java & related executables.

Comment: It seems like you can use `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` as well, correct?

Answer (score 33):

To **Set JAVA_HOME / PATH for a single user**, Login to your account and open .bash_profile file

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Set JAVA_HOME as follows using syntax export `JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>`. If your path is set to /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java, set it as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java
```

Set PATH as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
```

Feel free to replace /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07 as per your setup. Save and close the file. Just logout and login back to see new changes. Alternatively, type the following command to activate the new path settings immediately:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

OR

```
$ . ~/.bash_profile
```

Verify new settings:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ echo $PATH
```

Tip: Use the following command to find out exact path to which java executable under UNIX / Linux:

```
$ which java
```

Please note that the file ~/.bashrc is similar, with the exception that ~/.bash_profile runs only for Bash login shells and .bashrc runs for every new Bash shell.

**To Set JAVA_HOME / PATH for all user**, You need to setup global config in `/etc/profile` OR `/etc/bash.bashrc` file for all users:

```
# vi /etc/profile
```

Next setup PATH / JAVA_PATH variables as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
```

Save and close the file. Once again you need to type the following command to activate the path settings immediately:

```
# source /etc/profile
```

OR

```
# . /etc/profile
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to set *JAVA_HOME* to the *java* binary?

Answer (score 24):

You need to set the `$JAVA_HOME` variable.

In my case while setting up Maven, I had to set it up to where JDK is installed.

First find out where JAVA is installed:

```
$ whereis java
```

> java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

Now dig deeper:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
```

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Aug 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Dig deeper:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6464 Mar 14 18:28 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

As it is not being referenced to any other directory, we'll use this.

Open `/etc/environment` using nano:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Append the following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

export JAVA_HOME
```

Reload PATH using:

```
$. /etc/environment
```

Now:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Here is your output:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

Sources I referred to:

https://askubuntu.com/a/175519

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23427862/6297483

Comment: To dig deeper, you can use `readlink -f /usr/bin/java` as well

Answer (score 10):

if you have intalled only openJDK, the you should update your links, because you can have some OpenJDK intallation.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

after this

```
$gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add the following line in the file

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/YOUR_JAVA_VERSION
 export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
 export JAVA_HOME`

you can get you java version with

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 8):

To set up system wide scope you need to use the

`/etc/environment` file `sudo gedit /etc/environment`

is the location where you can define any environment variable. It can be visible in the whole system scope. After variable is defined system need to be restarted.

EXAMPLE :

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Add like following :

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/"
```

Here is the site you can find more : http://peesquare.com/blogs/environment-variable-setup-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If you update any entries do reload using `source /etc/environment` command

Comment: Or logout to activate the new variable automatically [(see this question)](https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting)

Answer (score 8):

- Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
- Type

  ```
  sudo gedit .bashrc
  ```
- Enter password of ubuntu user
- Go to last line of the file
- Type below code in new line

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=enter_java_path_here
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  eg: export JAVA_HOME=/home/pranav/jdk1.8.0_131
      export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Save the file
- Type

  ```
  source ~/.bashrc
  ```

  in terminal
- Done

Answer (score 8):

## How to install java packages:

Install desired java version / versions using official ubuntu packages, which are managed using alternatives:
`sudo apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk`
or/and other version: 
`sudo apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk`

Above answers are correct only when you have only one version for all software on your machine, and you can skip using update-alternatives. So one can quickly  hardcode it in .bashrc or some other place:
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`
but it's not healthy, as later on you may change the version.

## Correct way to set JAVA_HOME (and optionally JAVA_SDK, JAVA_JRE )

The correct way (and mandatory when you have more than one), is to detect what update-alternative is pointing to, and always use update-alternatives to switch active version.

Here are the suggestions for both: only specific unix account or for all accounts (machine level).

## 1. for a specific unix account only:

Use this if you don't have permissions to do it at machine level.

```
cat <<'EOF' >>~/.bashrc

export JAVA_HOME=$(update-alternatives --query java | grep Value | cut -d" " -f2 | sed 's!\(\/.*\)jre\(.*\)!\1!g')
export JDK_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JRE_HOME=${JDK_HOME}/jre/

EOF
```

## 2. To do it at machine level, and for all bourne shells, you need 2 steps:

2.a

```
cat <<'EOF' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/java_home_env.sh >/dev/null

export JAVA_HOME=$(update-alternatives --query java | grep Value | cut -d" " -f2 | sed 's!\(\/.*\)jre\(.*\)!\1!g')
export JDK_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JRE_HOME=${JDK_HOME}/jre/

EOF
```

As your shell might not be set as interactive by default, you may want to do this also:
2.b

```
cat <<'EOF' | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc >/dev/null
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
EOF
```

PS: There should be no need to update the $PATH, as update-alternatives takes care of the link to /usr/bin/.
More on: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html

Comment: When I use option 1. above after installing "openjdk-11-jdk-headless" I get JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME both equal to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", which I assume it not correct.  At least Maven/mvn says "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.  
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE"
j

Answer (score 7):

Create/Open `~/.bashrc` file `$vim ~/.bashrc`
Add `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` as referring to your JDK path

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<your version of java>
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

Save file

Now type `java -version` it should display what you set in `.bashrc` file.

This will persist over sessions as well.

Example :

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. I was adding "" initially and that does not work on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

It should put java in your path, probably in `/usr/bin/java`.  The easiest way to find it is to open a term and type `which java`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Update `bashrc` file to add `JAVA_HOME`

   `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`
2. Add `JAVA_HOME` to `bashrc` file.

   `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<your version of java>`
   `export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin`
3. Ensure Java is accessible

   `java -version`
4. In Case of Manual installation of JDK, If you got an error as shown below

   ```
   Error occurred during initialization of VM
   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
   ```
5. Execute the following command in your JAVA_HOME/lib directory:

   `unpack200 -r -v -l "" tools.pack tools.jar`
6. Execute the following commands in your JAVA_HOME/jre/lib

   `../../bin/unpack200 rt.pack rt.jar
   ../../bin/unpack200 jsse.pack jsse.rar
   ../../bin/unpack200 charsets.pack charsets.jar`
7. Ensure Java is accessible

   `java -version`

Answer (score 4):

Once I've installed the openjdk version of the Java Development Kit on an Ubuntu machine, I use this procedure to create a JAVA_HOME environment variable that doesn't need to be changed after every version upgrade of the openjdk installation.

Firstly, I issue a command to discover the directory in which the java executables are located for this java installation.

```
echo $(readlink -e `which java` | xargs -0 dirname)
```

If I'm happy with the output from that, everything else can be derived from it.

## Configuring the JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables

Rather than adding more and more configurations to the `~/.bashrc` file I've found it a cleaner practice to create a separate small file that  `~/.bashrc` can "include" when it runs.

Let's call that file `~/.java_env_vars` (but you could name it whatever you wish).

### Add an "include condition" to the `~/.bashrc` file

Open `~/.bashrc` in any text editor and these lines to the end of the file:

```
# include the java environment configuration file here (if it exists)
if [ -f "$HOME/.java_env_vars" ]; then
    . $HOME/.java_env_vars
fi
```

### Create the Java environment variable configuration file

Open any text editor, create the Java environment configuration file `~/.java_env_vars` and add this content to it:

```
#1.  set a java_bin variable to the directory containing the actual Java executables.
java_bin=$(readlink -e `which java` | xargs -0 dirname)

#2. append "$java_bin" to the PATH environment variable
export PATH=$PATH:"$java_bin"

#3. assign the directory of the current Java installation to the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname "$java_bin")
```

NOTE: exporting the PATH and JAVA_HOME variables just ensures that they're always available wherever they're needed.

Source your `~/.bashrc` file (so that the changes you made to it are reflected) using the following command:

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

### Test the Java environment variable configuration

Open a new terminal console, and test the new Java environment variables by issuing this command:

```
echo "$PATH" && echo "$JAVA_HOME"
```

Output should be two lines, something like this:

```
/home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a Linux Lite 3.8 (It bases on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and a path change in the following file (with root privileges) with restart has helped.

```
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me simplify:

1. download JDK from Oracle Website : [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Extract it
3. Create a folder (jvm) in `/usr/lib/` i.e `/usr/lib/jvm`
4. move the extracted folder from the jdk to `/usr/lib/jvm/`

*Note : use terminal, `sudo`, `mv` command i.e. `sudo mv`

5. Create a `.sh` file at `/etc/profile.d/` eg: `/etc/profile.d/myenvvar.sh`
6. In the `.sh` file type

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

*Note : use terminal, `gedit` and `sudo` eg: `sudo gedit myenvvar.sh`

7. Turn Off the Computer, after all these steps and Restart it
8. Open Terminal , and type

`java -version`

9. Check the output , then type

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: My JAVA_HOME was set in /etc/profile.d/maven.sh. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Step1:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bash_profile
```

Step2:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/user/tool/jdk-8u201-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_201
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Step3:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

open jdk once installed resides generally in your `/usr/lib/java-6-openjdk`

As usual you would need to set the `JAVA_HOME`, classpath and Path.

In ubuntu 11.04 there is a environment file available in `/etc` where you need to set all the three paths. And then you would need to restart your system for the changes to take effect..

Here is a site to help you around
http://aliolci.blogspot.com/2011/05/ubuntu-1104-set-new-environment.html

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do now is to set the `“JAVA_HOME”` and `“PATH”` environment variables and then you are done. Enter the following commands to set your environment variables. Make sure that your environment variables point to a valid installation of JDK on your machine. For Ubuntu 18.04, the path is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

To check whether your JAVA_HOME path has been successfully saved, enter the following command to check.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: This works only for terminal session and nowhere else

Answer (score 1):

Open file `/etc/environment` with a text editor
Add the line `JAVA_HOME="[path to your java]"`
Save and close then run `source /etc/environment`

Answer (score 1):

Set java version from the list of installed. For see the list of the installed version run following command:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

Then set your java version according to the following command:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Once JDK  installed set the `JAVA_HOME` in environment

   `sudo nano /etc/environment` and add the line `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/"`
2. Add the configuration in `.bashrc`

`sudo nano ~/.bashrc` and add following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11/
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

3. refresh the new configuration with `source ~/.bashrc`
4. enter the command `java -version` and you can see the version installed on your machine

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether env var exists or not

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

if an env var exists with that name then the above command will return the env var Path. if it's return nothing then copy the env path first then execute below command. such as my java env path is  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation of Oracle Java:

1. Download the tarball (.tar file) from Oracle website
2. unzip it by `sudo tar -xvpzf fileName -C /installation_folder_name`
3. change the files permission and ownership
4. add the following two lines in `/etc/profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/abu/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

5. restart the machine and check by `java -version` and `javac -version`

Answer (score 0):

You can install the default Ubuntu(17.10) java from apt:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

And it will set the PATH for you, if instead you need to install specific version of Java you can follow  this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWDcC9QxcqE)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lines to set the path variables in the `/etc/environment`

```
echo export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
echo export JRE_HOME=/path/to/jre  | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

It should work.

**Note:**

You should reboot the system for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I installed **java 11 in my Ubuntu 20.04.** Setting up a JAVA_HOME for the same.

enter the this command to find out your ubuntu version --

```
swapnil@swapnil-vm:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

enter this command to find out the location of your jvm --

```
swapnil@swapnil-vm:~$ whereis jvm
jvm: /usr/lib/jvm
```

open .bashrc in any editor of your choice --

```
nano .bashrc
```

add the following lines --

```
## setting JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

now you are good to go!! 
open a new terminal and enter the command --

```
ehco $JAVA_HOME
```