# Installing OpenJDK on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, java

I'm trying to get my hands dirty with Ubuntu and Eclipse. Going through manuals and online guides, I was able to install Ubuntu 13.04 and Eclipse Juno, but when I try to run Eclipse, it tells me that I need to install JRE first. I went ahead and tried the following (after consulting some more manuals):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

but it ends up with an error telling about some missing dependencies. Same thing happens if I replace `jre` with `jdk` in the above command. I tried to install through Software Center too, but that results in the same error as well; graphical version though :).

**EDIT**

Here is the exact error message (when installing through Software Center:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
openjdk-7-jre: 

Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2) but 7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2 is to be installed
Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:3.0-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
```

Interestingly, Ubuntu acknowledges this to be a problem and asks me whether I want to report it. Secondly, as evident from [apt-get manual](http://www.ss64.com/bash/apt-get.html), Software Center should installs all dependencies automatically.

Comment: You need to set java path i guess. [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Is the question really if it's supposed to be that error prone? Besides likely being ot, without knowing what's actually happening, I doubt anybody can help. Personally I use the Oracle jdk anyway, bit that's a separate issue.

Comment: So install the dependencies...

Comment: @AmanArora: Java is not installed yet!

Comment: @DaveNewton: Added some more info, see if this helps.

Comment: @JimGarrison: apt-get and Software Center are supposed to install all the dependencies automatically.