# JRE/java command not found

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to install JRE on Ubuntu 13.10. I followed this [guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-oracle-java-6-7-8-on-ubuntu-13-10/). When I run "java -version" it says "command not found"...

This is the result of "sudo find / -name java"

```
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/ure/share/java
/usr/local/java
/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
/usr/java
```

Comment: That may not be enough. You will want to check out this question, and follow the instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu

Comment: Is /usr/java/bin on your path?

Comment: can you paste the output of `dpkg -l | grep openjdk` command here

Comment: Your java successfully installed or not?

Comment: You can follow [this popular askubuntu guide here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Basically `command not found` happens when you didn't set up the PATH of installed java.

[This guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk) here covers more about how to install java on a ubuntu machine completely, but here I'm just going to present how to setup your java runnable:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin/java" 1
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
```

and then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Choose the one that has `/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin/java` in the options.

Comment: it doesn't work... Now the error at java -version is: /usr/bin/java: 2: /usr/bin/java: Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: According to your comment of @Jay's answer, I think the installation of java is broken on your machine. Try to re-install it and test it again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your Java bin full path /jre1.7.0_51/bin to the PATH variable in your Shell window.
Like this

```
        export PATH:$PATH:/jre1.7.0_51/bin
```

You can check the existing PATH by typing echo $PATH in your Shell window.

Comment: Do I have to type this on terminal?

Comment: it doesn't modify the PATH... this is the error: PATH:/jre1.7.0_51/binbash: export: "PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/jre1.7.0_51/bin": not a valid identifier

Comment: Please type "echo $PATH" and paste the results.

Comment: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Ok this shows there is no java in your path. Now you need to type the full path of your java bin folder. For example "export PATH:$PATH:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin". Then try "echo $PATH" again it should include the java path.

Comment: Same error... Not a valid identifier and PATH without java

Comment: You need to find the java installed location and give it correctly in the PATH. Try command "which java" to find the java location.

Comment: Which java returns /usr/bin/java. I tried to give it in the PATH but it returns the same error about identifier. By the way, the location you suggested me /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin) it exists.

EDIT: /usr/bin/java is not a directory, is it normal?

Comment: I restarted PC and now my path is: "/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin" but it still stays "file or directory does not exists" ... If I run java -version it returns: "/usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file"