# Maven compilation error: how to view details

Tags: maven

When I ran my maven project with `mvn -X clean package`, it showed the compilation error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project 3six5: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project 3six5: Compilation failure.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
```

However, no details on where the compilation error is. How can I find out what went wrong?

Comment: can you add content from pom.xml?

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed this issue by commenting out the compilerVersion tag from maven-compiler-plugin configuration. It seems there is conflict in version I used with Hibernate.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
<!--            <fork>true</fork> -->
<!--            <compilerVersion>${jdk.version}</compilerVersion> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue when setting up a Vaadin app on Ubuntu 20.04. at first I installed  sudo apt install default-jdk which installed java-11-openjdk-amd64.

The error was from the jdk-11 release because the app requires some older binaries  so I installed jdk-8
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk

then followed [How to set Java environment path in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu) to set the $JAVA_HOME path

After running mvn package the build was successful