# how can I run Java code while i have JDK and JRE installed on windows?

Tags: java

I am new in java programming and now i am testing a helloworld code to test. I use the command
`javac HelloWorld.java` in the console folder it's create a file `HelloWorld.class` . When i am running the command `java HelloWorld` i get

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 ...

I have to mention that i have JDK 14.0.2 installed and JRE ( for minecraft and server :) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again - during running Java program from Ubuntu terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671412/error-a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again)

Comment: yes , thanks @Svirin . the command was "javac -target 8 -source 8 `file`" .

Comment: The command should be `java HelloWorld` without the `.java`, but more important, when you type in the `java` command are you sure it's executing the one you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

Don't run java HelloWorld.Java instead
Run java HelloWorld   ie without .java extensions.

Comment: Isn’t java 14 able to compile and run in a single step?