# Spark: IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'

Tags: python, apache-spark

Getting the error when running `.toPandas()`, I've tried the solution mentioned in [Pyspark error - Unsupported class file major version 55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55) and [Pyspark .toPandas(): 'Unsupported class file major version 55'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989432/pyspark-topandas-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55) but without success.

I.e., as of now, my .bash_profile looks like:

```
...
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
...
```

And running `java -version` in terminal gives:

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Full error log:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.collectToPython.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-198b8ee6e584> in <module>()
      1 df3 = df2.select('col').na.drop()
----> 2 print(df3.toPandas())
      3 #print(df3.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).toPandas())

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   2140 
   2141         # Below is toPandas without Arrow optimization.
-> 2142         pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
   2143 
   2144         dtype = {}

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    531         """
    532         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 533             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    534         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    535 

~/anaconda3/envs/en_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect I somehow had multiple Java installations that caused the error. Solved it by running (a bit unorthodox) `$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/*` and then reinstalling from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html, at the time version: 'Mac OS X x64  245.92 MB   jdk-8u201-macosx-x64.dmg'.

Answer (score 3):

You can run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

to select a different installation of Java. Spark 2.xx requires Java 8.

Comment: Perfect! And after you do that for `javac`, you may also need to do the same for `java`

Comment: I was running into this issue and changing my java version to 8 fixed this problem.