# pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know this question seems to be duplicated as there are some similar problems have been uploaded but none of em can solve my problem.
I've tried everything mentioned here [Pyspark error - Unsupported class file major version 55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55)

My PATH variable is as follows:-
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64

My spark code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os,shutil

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

rdd = spark.read.csv("file:///home/karan/Ubuntu Files/ExportExcel2.csv",header=True,sep=",",multiLine="True")

try:
    ch=int(input("1. Patient Count\n2. Medicine Recommendation\nChoice:-")) 
    if(ch==1):
        ch=int(input("Enter number of fields you want to analyze:- "))
        print("Enter field names:- ")
        l=[]  
        for i in range(ch):
            l.append(input())
        rs=rdd.groupBy(*l).count().sort('count',ascending=False).select(*l,"count")
        rs.show()
    else:
        print("Now you messed up")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Can someone tell me where is the problem, this is what my csv file looks like:

```
"ID","Doctor","Disease","Symptoms Recorded","Severeness","Prescribed medicine"
"1","Phillip Mcneill","Cold","sore throat;runny nose;coughing","7","Tylenol"
"2","Ryan Griffiths","Anxiety Disorder","Panic;fear;Sleep problems;Shortness of breath","1","diazepam"
"3","Logan Needham","Anxiety Disorder","Panic;fear;Cold;sweaty;numb or tingling hands or feet","1","oxazepam"
"4","Britney Sinclair","Diabetes","Hunger and fatigue;Dry mouth and itchy skin","2","acarbose"
"5","Aiden Clayton","Anxiety Disorder","Panic;fear;Sleep problems;Shortness of breath","6","lorazepam"
"6","Lynn Oatway","Cold","sore throat;runny nose;coughing;sneezing;watery eyes","2","Tylenol"
"7","Jaylene Campbell","Diabetes","Hunger and fatigue;Dry mouth and itchy skin; Blurred vision;Yeast infections","7","acarbose"
"8","Remy Mcgee","Anxiety Disorder","Panic;fear;Sleep problems;Shortness of breath;Cold;sweaty;numb or tingling hands or feet","3","alprazolam"
"9","Paula Ulyatt","ADD","disorganized;Lack focus;Inattention","9","Concerta"
"10","Danny Roscoe","Diabetes","Hunger and fatigue;Dry mouth and itchy skin; Blurred vision;Yeast infections","4","glimepiride"
```

And this is the error that pop up everytime I try to run my code:

```
2019-03-04 07:58:54 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, ubuntu resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.43.120 instead (on interface ens33)
2019-03-04 07:58:54 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/home/karan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-03-04 07:58:55 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/karan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.csv.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.MultiLineCSVDataSource$.infer(CSVDataSource.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.inferSchema(CSVDataSource.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:617)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HAS.py", line 11, in <module>
    rdd = spark.read.csv("file:///home/karan/Ubuntu Files/ExportExcel2.csv",header=True,sep=",",multiLine="True")
  File "/home/karan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 472, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/home/karan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/karan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not the _answers_ work for you. Unless the _question_ you have is actually different, and you explain in which way it is, it's still a duplicate. You can either leave a comment on the original question, or explain how this is different. Otherwise you'll likely just get the same answers here.