# Pyspark throws IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55' when trying to use udf

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have following problem while using udfs in pyspark.

As long as I don't use any udfs my code works well. There are no problems with performing simple operations like selecting columns, or using sql functions like concat. As soon as I perform action on DataFrame that uses udf, program crash with following exception:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/Users/szymonk/Desktop/Projects/SparkTest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.3.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
19/06/05 09:24:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/szymonk/Desktop/Projects/SparkTest/Application.py", line 59, in <module>
    transformations.select(udf_example(col("gender")).alias("udf_example")).show()
  File "/Users/szymonk/Desktop/Projects/SparkTest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 378, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/Users/szymonk/Desktop/Projects/SparkTest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Users/szymonk/Desktop/Projects/SparkTest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Unsupported class file major version 55'
```

I've tried changing JAVA_HOME as proposed in: [Pyspark error - Unsupported class file major version 55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55) but it didn't help.

There is nothing fancy in my code. I am only defining a simple udf function that should return lenght of values inside column "Gender"

```
from pprint import pprint
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, struct, array, udf, concat, trim, when
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

transformations = spark.read.csv("Resources/PersonalData.csv", header=True)

udf_example = udf(lambda x: len(x))
transformations.select(udf_example(col("gender")).alias("udf_example")).show()
```

I'm not sure if it is significant but i'm using Pycharm on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, 
i had to switch boot jdk of Pycharm (2xshift -> jdk -> select jdk 1.8)

Answer (score 0):

I just switched from pySpark 2.4.7 back to 2.4.2 and it worked both with python 3.6 and 3.7