# Error reading in multiple json files Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read about 300 single json files into pyspark. I can read a single one, but as soon as I use a wildcard it throughs an error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56'
```

I've tried applying the following code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(appName='azure_test', conf=conf)
sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

data = sqlContext.read.json('test_1*.json')
```

I'd expect the output to be a DF of the jsons but instead got the error as mentioned above.

Comment: Try the below code 
text = sc.textFile("file1.json,file2.json")
ddff = spark.read.json(text)

Comment: Which version of Java are u using to run spark?

Comment: @ dassum that worked but now when I try to use .count() on the df the same error is thrown

Comment: @shu I'm running java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark error - Unsupported class file major version 55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]")
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").getOrCreate()

text = sc.textFile("file1,file2...")
ddff = spark.read.json(text)
```

or put all the files in some folder and use the folder location

```
sqlContext.read.json("/tmp/test")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no issues with your code but Spark not yet compatible with [Java-12](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24417).

Run with [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55) and then try to read the json files

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(appName='azure_test', conf=conf)
sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

data = sqlContext.read.json('test_1*.json')
```

***from Spark-2.0:***

```
spark.read.option("multiline",True).json("<file_path_to_test_1*.json>").show()
```

Comment: @Russel did it worked? If yes accept the answer to close the thread :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work