# error: Unsupported class file major version 56 in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

My code which I am running in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from datetime import datetime
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
simple_data = sc.parallelize ([1,2,3])     
simple_data.count()
```

Error which is received:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark error - Unsupported class file major version 55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55)

Comment: To fix this issue I edited the bash_profile to ensure java 1.8 is used as the global default as follows:
    touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
Adding
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) 
and saving within text edit. This does not work