# IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

i am a beginner in spark. i want to do the machine learning so i want to understand this error

`(train_data, test_data, predict_data) = Churn_clean.randomSplit([0.8, 0.18, 0.02], 24)
print("Number of records for training: " + str(train_data.count()))
print("Number of records for evaluation: " + str(test_data.count()))
print("Number of records for prediction: " + str(predict_data.count()))`

`IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 56'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark error - Unsupported class file major version 55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55)

Comment: That's because the underlying Java version. Check which Java version are you using and JAVA_HOME environment value.

Comment: yes I configured my environment variable

Comment: JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2