# No FileSystem for scheme: s3 using pyspark while reading parquet s3 file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bucket with a few small Parquet files that I would like to consolidate into a bigger one.

To do this task, I would like to create a spark job to consume and write a new file.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .master("local") \
                    .appName("Consolidated tables") \
                    .getOrCreate()

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "access")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "secret")

df = spark.read.parquet("s3://lake/bronze/appx/contextb/*")
```

This code is throwing me an Exception: `No FileSystem for scheme: s3`. If I switch to `s3a://...`, I got the error: `Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found`.

I'm trying to run this code as `python myfile.py`.

Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download this hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar (or latest version) and configure this jar available for spark

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config("spark.jars", "/path/to/hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar")\
        .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Now I got the error `Unsupported class file major version 56`.

Comment: java version should be 1.8.Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55

Answer (score 0):

```
from boto3.session import Session
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .master("local") \
                    .appName("Consolidated tables") \
                    .getOrCreate()

ACCESS_KEY='your_access_key'
SECRET_KEY='your_secret_key'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')

df = spark.read.parquet("s3://lake/bronze/appx/contextb/*")
```