# Spark BinaryType to Scala/Java

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm doing a spark app using scala with following data:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|        id|                data|
+----------+--------------------+
|    id1   |[AC ED 00 05 73 7...|
|    id2   |[CF 33 01 61 88 9...|
+----------+--------------------+
```

The schema shows:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: binary (nullable = true)
```

**I tried to convert this dataframe into a map object, with id being key and data being value**

I have tried:

```
df.as[(String, BinaryType)].collect.toMap
```

but I got following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.types.BinaryType
- field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.types.BinaryType", name: "_2")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
```

Comment: Should be `Array[Byte]`.

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryType` is a Spark `DataType`. It maps in Scala/Java to `Array[Byte]`.

Try `df.as[(String, Array[Byte])].collect.toMap`.

Make sure you've imported your sessions `implicits`, e.g., `import spark.implicits._` so you gain the ability to create `Encoder[T]` instances implicitly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, the error is: result.as[(String, Array[Byte])].collect.toMap
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)

Comment: You are likely running the wrong Java version. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-55

Comment: Source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/BinaryType.html (The data type representing Array[Byte] values. Please use the singleton DataTypes.BinaryType.)