# use sc.parallelize() in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[image]

Hi , I'm new to scala and trying to use sc.parallalize() and running into the error as attached.

Comment: Please, don't post code and errors as screenshots, just post the (correctly formatted) text. Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583199/pyspark-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Java version error, was able to install correct version of Java .