# java javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: java, rest, web-services, ssl, https

I've a webserver running on tomcat 8.5. I have imported the certificate using this solution:
["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

this is the exactly flow and the problem: I've rest resource on this url https://localhost:8443/Test/prova/HelloWorld and I'm using Jersey. On a virtual machine (on the same machine) I've a cas server running on tomcat 9. Now I'm trying to use sso. I login in the cas page and when it redirect me on the service requested then I got this full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/Test] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:443)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1581)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:459)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:434)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1313)
    ... 41 more
```

EDIT:
In the vm where is the cas server I've done the following things:

1. generated a certificate with SAN ip
2. imported it in cacerts

now I've another exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:443)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
Root Cause

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1581)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
Root Cause

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:350)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:259)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1313)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1581)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
Root Cause

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:233)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:141)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)
    java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:345)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:259)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1313)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1581)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
Root Cause

java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:423)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:233)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:141)
    java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)
    java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:345)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:259)
    java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1313)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1581)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
```

I've also imported the same certificate in the host machine

Comment: did you add java home to path? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu/16435626

Comment: yes it points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

Comment: and did you make changes to lib\security\cacerts file of java 11?

Comment: yes, but I've doubt about the name the certs must have in the cacerts. Does it must have a specific name to have found?

Comment: yes I think the name should equals to cacerts

Comment: And be careful that doing the steps right because if you don't know what are you doing you will get into troubles

Comment: Please be more specific. Is the exception in (Java) code running in the tomcat and trying to connect to something else, or in a Java client trying to connect to the tomcat server? In either case are you using the new 11 client, URLConnection, Apache, Jersey, or other middleware? Which of these programs run on which systems, and which ones are using the identified JVM? @Spara: that makes no sense; java.library.path is not used for any config; the only thing it _might_ be used for is tcnative/APR code and that shouldn't be in the conf dir.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I think I've fixed the first exception, now I get only this exception "No subject alternative names present"

Answer (score 0):

(for the revised question)

From [the javadoc for X509ExtendedTrustManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html)

> To prevent man-in-the-middle attacks, hostname checks can be done to verify that the hostname in an end-entity certificate matches the targeted hostname. TLS does not require such checks, but some protocols over TLS (such as HTTPS) do. ... RFC 2818 defines both the server identification and the client identification specification for the "HTTPS" algorithm.

and from [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)

> In general, HTTP/TLS requests are generated by dereferencing a URI.
> As a consequence, the hostname for the server is known to the client.
> If the hostname is available, the client MUST check it against the
> server's identity as presented in the server's Certificate message,
> in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. ...

[skip parts about name matching, which is slightly more complicated]

> In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a
> hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present
> in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.

(By the way, that odd-looking capitalization is not a mistake, it is a consequence of the naming conventions in ASN.1, which is used to define, among many other things, the X.509 certificates used in SSL/TLS/HTTPS.)

The stacktrace shows **jasig is trying to connect to a HTTPS server identified by IP address, but the certificate supplied by that server does not have** the SubjectAlternativeName (abbreviated SubjectAltName or just SAN) extension containing **the IP address as required**. Options are:

- the server should actually be identified by name, which can be and (in this case presumably is) in CommonName attribute of Subject field, instead of SAN extension. You need to change the hostname in the URL jasig tries to access, and I don't know enough about it to comment on that.
- the server should actually be identified by IP address, and its certificate was issued/created incorrectly. You or someone should get and use a corrected certificate for the server. Since there are zillions of ways of obtaining or creating a certificate and you don't say which you used, or could use instead, I can't give any details.
- the usual stackoverflow approach: "I just want some connection and I don't care if it's the right server". `HttpsURLConnection` allows use of a custom `HostnameVerifier` (linked in the javadoc above) at either the instance level or JVM-wide (default)  which can accept a server cert (and connection) even though it doesn't satisfy the normal rules. I don't know whether or how jasig gives you control over the (Https)URLConnection instance or factory(ies) used for it, which would let you set the instance; if you need to set the default that is in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) .