# Is it necessary to set the JAVA_HOME variable every time system is restarted?

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, java-home

I have recently formatted my system and installed Ubuntu 16.0.4 and done all necessary setup for running react-native project.But since then every time i restart the system, getting following error,

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I am setting path by using following command,

```
export JAVA_Home=/home/syamkishore/Downloads/android-studio/jre
```

If i do so error will be cleared. But if I restart the system again same error occurs.

Can somebody suggest the permanent solution to set the Java path once forever?
Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Java environment path in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

sudo gedit /etc/profile
Add following lines in end

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH

Please see below link. It explains how to set the java path permanently.

[How to set the java class path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu)