# How to set JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME variable for open JDK11

Tags: java-11, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy the web application using tomcat 9.0. I am getting below error:

```
 Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

after executing `.\catalina.bat` run command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat needs the JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables.
You need to setup your JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables as shown step by step in the link below:

For Windows: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

For Ubuntu: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux/

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: The ubuntu link does not even mention JRE_HOME. I suggest following the answer posted here :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59012171/1616719