# Kafka setup java exe path issue on Ubuntu

Tags: java, apache-kafka, installation, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to setup Kafka on Ubuntu 18.04. Used the kafka_2.11-2.1.1.tgz. Have jdk8, JAVA_HOME etc all fine.

$JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"

Set and started Kafka  `systemd[1]: Started kafka.service.`
 When I issue my first test command
`kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TutorialTopic`
`/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 306: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java`: **Not a directory**

As you can notice I have this *extra/duplicate*  `/bin/java` in the java executable path in the end. Where is this coming from I don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $JAVA_HOME seems to be incorrect.

[Checkout setting $JAVA_HOME environment variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu)

Comment: changed JAVA_HOME - it but still same error. For Kafka do we also have to setup JRE_HOME

Comment: I think JAVA_HOME needs to be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`  - This finally worked