# How do i set up java 16 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to make Minecraft mods with Fabric, but when I run `./gradlew genSources`, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/andrew/Desktop/Minecraft Mods/TEST/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '0.8-SNAPSHOT']
> Failed to apply plugin 'fabric-loom'.
   > You are using an outdated version of Java (11). Java 16 or higher is required.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 701ms
```

I uninstalled java 11 and installed java 16 with the deb file from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html. Once I do that, I get this error when running `./gradlew genSources`:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

How do I fix this? Here is the tutorial I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JZ7bnk3oiM

Comment: JAVA_HOME environment variable is used to determine the Java installation location. Check this link to find out how to set it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu