# setting environment variables on Linux startup

Tags: linux, environment-variables, startup

There are several entries in stackoverflow to this subject.
e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Why does it not work on my computer with Debian-10 (Buster)? I did 3 trial:

1. put a file named *90java.conf* below */etc/environment.d* holding

   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
2. put a file named *java-env.sh* below */etc/profile.d* holding

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
3. add the same text at the end to */etc/profile*

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

and restarted Debian at each trial.

Than opened a command window and entered

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

The response was always an empty line. Like to understand what I do not have grasped about environment variables on startup.

*added later:*

Entering the *export* statement to */etc/bash.bashrc* solved my problem.

However, I'd like to understand what is different to the */etc/environment* or */etc/profile* approach. Why do environment variables do not show up in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Setting like this are only relevant in a specific context. For example your shell, where you want to work with software and tools.

Thus, the solution is actually much simpler than all what you have tried. You have to do this in your private/local environment. But it depends on your shell.

If you have bash (or similar shells bash, sh, dash,...) best is edit the file `~/.profile` and add `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` there. If you have other shells find our the correct equivalent file. For csh it would be `~/.cshrc` etc.

Comment: What is the specific context for *all users*? As I understood the link I gave above, adding environment variable definitions to */etc/profile* should be relevant for all users. But I do something wrong and like to understand what is wrong.