# How can I change Java version 1.7 to 1.8 in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-8, java-7

My Ubuntu machine have installed both java 1.7 and 1.8. But when I checked Java version it shows version Java 1.7 as the snapshot below. When I check Java alternative version I can see "java-8-openjdk-amd64". I am beginner to Ubuntu. Can anyone help me to change it to 1.8?

[image]

Comment: `$ sudo update-alternatives --config java` .... https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the envirnoment variable to java 1.8
using this method
Edit the /etc/profile

```
    sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add these lines in the end

```
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
    export JAVA_HOME
    export JRE_HOME
    export PATH
```

like mentioned in this answer

[How to set Java environment path in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

[sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) is a good Open source version manager for Java. It provides commands to search & install multiple versions of Java and switch between versions with

```
sdk use java 1.8.363-open
```

It can also manage other tools like Maven.