# Unable to install Java using terminal in Ubuntu 22

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, deb

I have been trying to install java using deb file using terminal. However terminal keep on showing 3 lines and exiting.

```
(Reading database ... 212600 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack jdk-18_linux-x64_bin.deb ...
Unpacking jdk-18 (18.0.1.1-ga) over (18.0.1.1-ga) ...
Setting up jdk-18 (18.0.1.1-ga) ...
shiddalingayya@shiddalingayya-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2:~/Downloads$
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPshE.png)

Comment: I think your question should be asked in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), the StackOverflow is about coding. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the installation seems to finish successfully. I don't see any errors.
What you might ask is why can't you use the `java` or `javac` in the command line.

You need to set your `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables first, before the `java` command becomes available everywhere.

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu) to see how to do that.